# Rails Displaying Post Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to assign a post category to a new post at front end. Post is being created with no errors but, looking in rails console; postcategory_id is showing nil.

Any idea why field is showing nil?

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 85, content: "New post", postcover: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-28 20:46:46", updated_at: "2016-07-28 20:46:46", post_id: nil, postcategory_id: nil, postcategory_name: nil>]>
```

The only way I'm able to generate the postcategory_id is by editing and saving the existing post.

Form:

```
.....<%= f.collection_select :postcategory_id, Postcategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a category" }, input_html: { class: "control-label" } %>
```

Create Action:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    @post.postcategory_id = params[:postcategory_id]

    respond_to do |f|
        if @post.save 
            f.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Post created!" }
        else
            f.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Error: Couldn't create post with no text." }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `postcategory_id` is coming in `params` and not in nested `params[:post]`? Can you show how you are creating the form and what parameters you are receiving in rails log when submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use byebug. Add `buybug` in the first line of create action, refresh the page, go to console to check the value of params[:postcategory_id]

Comment: @kellernova that's a good gem for debugging, thanks for pointing it out. It helped me to find out where the issue was. Btw correct name is byebug

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
= f.input :postcategory_id, :as => :select, :collection => Postcategory.all, :prompt => 'Select a category', input_html: { class: "control-label" }
```

And comment out the line:

```
@post.postcategory_id = params[:postcategory_id]
```

on the create action.

Comment: Thanks @Pledges, I commented our]t `@post.postcategory_id = params[:postcategory_id]` and used simple_form. I works fine!

Comment: The only issue I need to get around is all the categories show on my local machine but not showing on the server. See (http://preachout.com/posts/8) drop down of 3 categories which show on my local machine are not showing in production. Although, db for categories were migrated in production with no error. syntax for drop down menu..layouts/_nav.html.erb `<% Postcategory.all.each do |postcategory| %>
        <li><%=  link_to postcategory.name, posts_path(postcategory: postcategory.name) %></li>
        <% end %>`

Comment: Issue has been fixed by manually creating various categories on the production server (using rails console)